# Flutter OpenContainer Animation behavior

Tags: flutter

I'm doing a simple open container from a card.

I am seeing that the constructor of the widget being opened is called multiple times.

Is this normal behavior? I was planning to do some heavy initialization by getting data from the backend, but don't want to do it in the constructor if the animation is designed to create the object again and again.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OpenContainer(
      closedColor: Colors.transparent,
      transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      closedBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback action) => Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
            onTap: () => action(),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  session.sessionName,
                  style: textTheme.headline6,
                ),
                Text('Week:' + session.week.toString()),
                Text('Session:' + session.sessionDay.toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      openBuilder: (session.completed)
          ? (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
              ReviewCompletedSession(session: session)
          : (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
              ManageSession(key: ValueKey(session.id), session: session),
      tappable: false,
    );
}
```

The Manage session widget constructor right now is a simple one.

```
ManageSession({
    Key key,
    @required this.session,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    print('Constructor called');
  }
```

Comment: yes animation rebuilds the widget when the animation value changes, if you need to do some heavy initialisation, i recommend you to do it in a separate class/controller/store, which informs the UI when its done initialising, I guess you are using a stateless widget, if you want to use initialisation in the constructor itself, use stateful widget

Comment: Thanks. Looks like when I use the stateful widget, the initState is still being called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stateful widget, and call a async function to initialise once finished call setState
(This answer was posted mistakenly, I was trying to comment, now I made it look like an answer)